# How can i specify the authentication db in Spring Data Mongo Template

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is there a way to specify the authentication database with a mongo template?

I found a way with db-factory (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-789 ) but i don't use db-factory.

How can i specify the authentication database?